# boreh pri hagafen and hamotzi during the week

Tags: halacha, blessing, grapes-wine, priorities, bread

On Shabbat and holidays, we say kiddush before hamotzi (I think because hamotzi would normally cover the wine? Is that right?).  During the week, what is the proper procedure? Is it to say hagafen and then hamotzi like on Shabbat? Hamotzi and then hagafen? Just hamotzi? Also, what is the deal with the bracha achrona?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Proper procedure? I don't think there is a preference. Hamotzi does not exempt wine ever ([Shulchan Aruch OC 174](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%A2%D7%93):1) and if you drank wine before the bread it continues to exempt wine drunk after the bread (:4). Also, the after blessing on the bread exempts the wine, even if wine was only drunk before the bread, and certainly if it was drunk during the meal itself (:6).